# Entropy of a beta-binomial compound distribution

Tags: probability, expectation, information-theory, entropy

I am trying to calculate the entropy of a beta-Bernoulli process, which is a special case of the beta-binomial process for when $n=1$.

I believe that the correct approach is to take the Beta-Binomial PMF (with $n=1$):

$$
P(k \mid 1,\alpha ,\beta )= {1 \choose k}{\frac  {{\mathrm  {B}}(k+\alpha ,1-k+\beta )}{{\mathrm  {B}}(\alpha ,\beta )}}\!
$$
where $\text{B}(\cdot)$ is the Beta function, plug it into the Boltzmann-Shannon entropy.

---

Here is how far I have got, reminding ourselves of the model:

$$
X\sim \operatorname {Bin} (n,p)
$$
then
$$
P(X=k \mid p,n)=L(p|k)={n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k}
$$
with $n=1$ we get
$$
P(X=k \mid p,1)=L(p \mid k)={1 \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{1-k}
$$
so we are saying that $X$ is defined on a binary space $\{0,1 \}$ also
$$
{\binom {n}{k}}={\frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}} = /n=1 / = {\frac {1!}{k!(1-k)!}}
$$

Recall also that entropy is defined as:

$$
\mathrm{H} (X) =\mathbb {E} [-\log(\mathrm {P} (X))]
$$

---

Lets plug in our PMF expression (defined at the top) for the Beta-Binomial, into the definition for entropy:

$$
\mathrm{H} [X = k] = \mathbb{E} \left [ 
- \log{\left (\frac{{\binom{1}{k}}}{\mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha,\beta \right )}} \mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha + k,\beta - k + 1 \right )} \right )}
\right] 
$$
which simplifies to
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{H} [X = k] &= \mathbb{E} \left [ 
\log{\mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha,\beta \right )}} 
- \log \mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha + k,\beta - k + 1 \right )}  - \log{{\binom{1}{k}}}
\right ] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left [\log{\mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha,\beta \right )}}\right ] 
- \mathbb{E} \left[\log \mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha + k,\beta - k + 1 \right )}\right ]
- \mathbb{E} \left [\log{{\binom{1}{k}}} \right].
\end{align}
$$

Which reduces to:

$$
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{H} [X =k] = \log{\mathrm{B}{\left (\alpha,\beta \right )}} 
- \psi(\alpha+k) + \psi(\alpha + \beta + 1)
- \mathbb{E} \left [\log{{\binom{1}{k}}} \right].
\end{equation}
$$

where $\psi(\cdot)$ is the digamma function. The problem is now the last expectation:

$$
\mathbb{E} \left [\log{{\binom{1}{k}}} \right]
$$

Not sure if this makes sense; how can one take the expectation of a binomial coefficient? I feel like I have gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: That is just a constant

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\log {1 \choose k} \right] = \log {1 \choose k} 
$$

Comment: .....oooh, so assuming everything else is correct, I just substitute the constant and I have found my entropy?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Well this is very embarrassing I just realised that for the given domain $k \in \{0,1\}$ that constant is just that; _constant_ as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\mathbb{E} \left [\log \frac{1}{k} \right] = \left [\log \frac{1}{k} \right] = \log 1 = 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that when you turn a Binomial (n, p) r.v in a Bernoulli (1, p) r.v. then the space of possible values (number of successes in $n$ independent trials with probability of success $p$) changes from (0, 1, .... , n) to (0, 1) hence $P(X=0)=1-p$ and $P(X=1)=p$.

The p.m.f of the Beta-Bernoulli $(1, \alpha, \beta)$ r.v. will be

$$P(X=0)= \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$$
$$P(X=1)= \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)}$$

Hence the correct answer to your question turns out to be:

$$H(X)= -\left\{\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \log \left[\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\right] + \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)} \log \left[\frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)}\right]\right\}= -\left\{\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \log (\beta) + \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha+\beta)} \log (\alpha)\right\}$$